# AJAX call to a PHP file not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am practicing doing simple AJAX calls to localhost but experiencing trouble. What I'm trying to do is send two textbox form values to PHP and then have it return a message to an empty div in my form upon successful reception via AJAX. My test.php is like this:

```
<?php

$num = htmlentities(substr($_POST["num"], 0, 7), ENT_QUOTES);
$name = htmlentities(substr($_POST["name"], 0, 50), ENT_QUOTES);

$result = "'$num ' + 'and' + ' $name' + ' values have been successfully AJAXd'";

echo json_encode($result);
```

jQuery:

```
  $("#form").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#msgcontainer").html("");
    $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    data: ("#num").serialize(), ("#name").serialize(),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",   
    dataType: "json"
      success: function(response) {
        $("#msgcontainer").html(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

When I try to submit, the page simply reloads and adds form values to the URL. I've been trying to solve this for about a day now, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I figured it out by trying things from every response. Not sure why it works without serialization... If someone knows, please explain. Working jQuery code:

```
  $("#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#msgcontainer").html("");
    $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    data: {
            num: $("#num").val(),
            name: $("#name").val()
          },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        $("#msgcontainer").html(response);
      }
    });
  });
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `$result = "{$num} and {$name} values have been successfully AJAXd";` would be the correct format

Comment: Could you share the HTML as well? Btw, you should have seen parse errors in the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things stand out immediately:

```
data: ("#num").serialize(), ("#name").serialize(),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

The first should be this (assuming you have two text boxes):

```
data: {
    num: $('#num').val(),
    name: $('#name').val()
},
```

And the `contentType:` line should not be there, otherwise you'll have an empty `$_POST`.

Lastly, `event` should be a function argument, i.e.:

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
```

Comment: This works, but why does it work without serialization?

Comment: @user3361043 When you pass a simple object as `data:` jQuery will do the serialisation for you.

Comment: I see. So when is it needed?

Comment: You can use `$(this).serialize()` to get a string which you can then pass using `data:`; this comes in handy when you have a number of input fields and you don't require special handling of the values.

Answer (score 1):

Your data parameter in your AJAX call is wrong, should be something like:

```
data: { num: $('#num').val() , name: $('#name').val() }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
```

`event` isn't defined anywhere. I'm guessing you meant `...submit(function(event) {`.

You should be seeing an error in the JavaScript console telling you "event is not defined" or "TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined."

Answer (score 0):

The data is not being sent properly. Consider replacing:

```
data: ("#num").serialize(), ("#name").serialize(),
```

With:

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

And then you may want to edit your `PHP` script so that you `concatenate` the strings instead of `summing` them.

Also pass the `event` param or simply use the following:

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    var event = arguments[0];
    event.preventDefault();
    ....
});
```

I doubt that you need `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`!

Answer (score 0):

good morning,

You have to serialize the entire form, like:

```
$("#yourform").serialize();
```

Instead of just field by field:

```
("#num").serialize(), ("#name").serialize()
```